# R - matrix multiplication - no error signaled

Tags: r

```
> x <- c(1,1) 
> m <- rbind(c(1,4),c(2,2))  
> m %*% x   # 1 
     [,1]
[1,]    5
[2,]    4
> x %*% m   # 2  
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    6
>
```

I can understand how and why the second multiplication works. In math a 1x2 (1 row, 2 columns) matrix can be multiplied by a 2x2 matrix.

But why does the first one work and why does it produce no error or warning at all? In math a 2x2 matrix cannot be multiplied by a 1x2 vector/matrix.

Note that if I initialize x like this below, and if I then multiply m to x, I get the same result as in the first example above.

```
> x <- cbind(c(1,1));
> x
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    1
> m %*% x   #  3  
     [,1]
[1,]    5
[2,]    4
```

So I think that this third example is the right way to do it.
Then why is the first example working OK without error or warning?

Comment: Apparently `R` treats a vector as a column vector and so there is no error. Try `m %*% t(x)`, which returns an error message

Comment: @DatamineR Yes, I suspect so. But see my 3rd example. Now 1st and 3rd work in the same way, but we initialized x differently in them. In the 3rd example x is actually an 2x1 matrix (as it should be). So... that's what I find confusing and counter-intuitive. I would just expect an error from 1st example but apparently in R it's not an error.

Answer (score 1):

Directly from the documentation, `?matmult`:

matmult {base}

*Multiplies two matrices, if they are conformable. **If one argument is a vector, it will be promoted to either a row or column matrix to make the two arguments conformable.** If both are vectors of the same length, it will return the inner product (as a matrix).*

So the following amounts to the same thing (ignoring attributes):

```
x %*% m
t(x) %*% m 
rbind(x) %*% m
```

and in the same way:

```
m %*% x
m %*% t(t(x))
m %*% cbind(x)
```

but `m %*% t(x)` or `t(t(x)) %*% m` will give you an error, because `t()` will return a `matrix` and the dimensions are now incompatible. This also illustrates, that the vector is better interpreted as a column- than a row-vector.